# iFrame to communicate with website

Tags: html, iframe, communication

To summarize the situation: I have an iFrame which loads a bunch of content. In this case, it loads courses which our customers can take part in. The descriptions of these courses are multilingual and should correspond to the user's language.

Accessing the language variable is very easy, but the tricky part is communicating with the iFrame.
So, how can I (easily) pass the language variable of the website to the iFrame?

Comment: You can use Cookies/SESSION OR GET method. Example: iframe src = 'example.php?lang=enus';

Comment: The language isn't stored in the URL... But Cookies/SESSION is a good start

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use a querystring variable for this purpose. Let's say that the ifram url is foo.com. When you have entered the page, and you know that the language is EN. Then, you create the url of the iframe with something like foo.com?language=DE